# File server distributed caching

Tags: architecture, filesystems, distributed

We have a very big file server (HTTP and/or FTP). Some files are then used by around 5 systems. For example, system A will use files A and B. Then System B will use files A and C.

Are there applications, preferably free or open source, that can cache those commonly used files inside the system?

I'm looking for Squid alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of interest, when you say "big" do you mean LOTS of files? or do you mean LOTS of requests? (or both?)  How often do the files change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)? I haven't used it myself but it seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about storing files in 100s of MBs then Hadoop would be my recommended choice to solve this problem. But according to the community Hadoop is not very suitable for files in kB or < 200-300MB.

For such cases most recommend HBase built on Hadoop. The combo provides high availability and scalability at the same time. But saying so Hadoop setup might be a bigger than one might want, e.g. a development/test cluster size is [recommended](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/03/clouderas-support-team-shares-some-basic-hardware-recommendations/) to consist of 4~5 servers, while production environment minimum is 10+ servers.

An effective alternate to squid web cache is [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/).